# How to convert a List<T> into a comma-separated list, using the class's Id property as the value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<User>` collection, and I want to create a comma seperated string using the User.Id property, so:

```
"12321,432434,123432452,1324234"
```

I have done it using a loop, but was hoping someone could show me the linq way?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In .NET 4:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.Id));
```

In .NET 3.5:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.Id.ToString()).ToArray());
```

The difference is that [.NET 4's overload list for `string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is wider than [the one in .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and the [overload you really want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) is one of the "new" ones:

```
public static string Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)
```

You can still do it in .NET 2.0, just using a `List<T>`-specific method instead of LINQ (I'm assuming you can still use C# 3):

```
string joined = string.Join(",", list.ConvertAll(x => x.Id.ToString())
                                     .ToArray());
```

Comment: so these are are null unfriendly also right?  i'll guard then.  btw, you don't answer these on your phone do you?

Comment: @codecompleting: Yes, these are null-unfriendly. Most things are :) I rarely *answer* on my phone, although I'll sometimes edit or add comments that way.

Comment: I added some safe initializing to my answer for nulls if you're concerned

Answer (score 2):

use

```
string myResult = string.Join (",", (from l in myList select l.ID.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: ToString() and ToArray() is not needed

Comment: @Magnus - What makes you think that? The method takes a `string[]`.

Comment: @hunter Takes in IEnumerable<T> also

Comment: It depends if it's `Join(string separator, params Object[] values)` or 
 `Join(string separator, params string[] value)`

Comment: @Magnus: It depends on the framework version you're using. See my answer.

Comment: you are both right - the difference is whether the OP uses .NET 3.5 or .NET 4 - the `ToArray` and the `ToString` are both not needed in .NET 4 . But since the OP didn't specify I gave the solution that works with both .NET versions...

Comment: depends on which one is called, but .NET 4 is more flexible http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx than 3.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: If not specified one would assume latest version

Comment: @Yahia: Note that using a query expression is more long-winded than calling Select directly.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - you are absolutley right :-) I came to Linq from SQL so the query expression syntax still feels a bit weird to me... :-)

Comment: @Yahia: It's well worth being familiar with both; each is useful in different scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Join( ",", list.Select( item => item.ID ).ToArray() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this list:

```
List<User> users = (GetUsers() ?? new List<User>())
   .Where(u => u != null).ToList();

// no more nulls
```

---

**.NET 3.5** - [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> Join(String, String())
>
> Join(String, String(), Int32, Int32)

**Example:**

```
return string.Join(",", users.Select(u => u.Id.ToString()).ToArray());
```

---

**.NET 4.0** - [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> Join(String, IEnumerable(Of String))
>
> Join(Of T)(String, IEnumerable(Of T))
>
> Join(String, Object()) // really? Just joining "stuff"?
>
> Join(String, String())
>
> Join(String, String(), Int32, Int32)

**Example**

```
return string.Join(",", users.Select(u => u.Id));
```

Comment: I'm always weary of linq, does it handle nulls or will this crash if users is null?

Comment: well, you should probably check if users is null before this. My guess it should be either empty or not, but not null unless that's something you're coding for.

Comment: @codecompleting: If the `users` value is null, this will throw an `ArgumentNullException` immediately. If there's a null value *within the list* it will throw a `NullReferenceException` when it gets to that point in the processing.