# Converting a List<T> into a comma separated list of values for all objects in another List

Tags: c#

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7588836/3199927) answer, but I need to do it for all objects in a `List` instead of just one.

Think of workouts, you might write:

> Bench Press: 135x10, 185x10, 225x8, 275x5, 315x3
>
> Dumbbell Press: 65x12, 85x12, 95x10, 100x8, 100x8

That is, you have a list of exercises, and each exercise has a list of sets/reps.  You want to, for each exercise in the list, convert its list of sets/reps into the form above.

The classes look like:

```
public class Workout
{
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

// Activity is an instance of an exercise,
// i.e., you bench press, dumbbell press, etc... all in one workout
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    public List<Set> Sets { get; set; }
}

// Sets just hold Weight and Reps
public class Set
{
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Reps { get; set; }
}
```

So, for each `Set` in an `Activity`, I want `set.Weight + "x" + set.Reps`, and for each `Activity` in an `Exercise`, I want:

```
"the string we just got for set 1, the string we just got for set 2"
```

Based on the answer I linked earlier, I've come up with this:

```
string.Join(",", 
     workout.Activities.Select(
         activity => activity.Sets.Select(
             set => set.Weight.ToString() + "x" + set.Reps.ToString()
         )
     ));
```

But that yields:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[MyLifts.Models.Set,System.String],System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[MyLifts.Models.Set,System.String],System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[MyLifts.Models.Set,System.String],System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[MyLifts.Models.Set,System.String],System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[MyLifts.Models.Set,System.String]

Comment: `...but that doesn't seem to work.`, what does it do? Give you an error? Not give you the string your want? Not compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have nested selects, the inner select returns an `IEnumerable<String>` which you can join, but the outer select returns an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<String>>`.

Are Exercise and Workout the same thing? Assuming they are try:

```
string.Join(",", 
 workout.Activities.Select(
     activity => activity.Exercise.Name + ": " + String.Join(",", 
         activity.Sets.Select(
              set => set.Weight.ToString() + "x" + set.Reps.ToString()
         )
     )
 ));
```

Comment: Okay, so that's pretty much it, except I'm getting one huge list of exercises, sets, and reps, i.e., "Bench: 225x5, 275x3 Dumbbell Bench: 85x12, 95x8" where I'd hope to get these into a list of string, i.e., Bench and Bumbbell bench are two different items in a List<String>.  I guess my question doesn't explain where I hope to store that, so: give me some time to figure that out, and I will most likely accept this answer.

Comment: To get what you describe you would only have to leave out the outer string.Join. The result of workout.Activities.Select will be an Enumerable of strings.