# Create delimited list from a list of object's property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects, one of the properties on the object is a string.

Is there a way to use `Join` and Linq create a delimited list of the string property in one line of code? If not, what is the least amount of code to accomplish this?

EXAMPLE:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public int MyInt { get; set; }
   public string MyString  { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a string using `Join` that contains a delimited list of all the `MyString` values in `MyObject`.

Something like this -

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList = GetMyObjectList(); //Contains a list of MyObject 

//I want to do something like this
string MyListOfMyStrings = String.Join(",", myObjectList.ForEach(x => x.Mystring));
```

MyListOfMyStrings will be set to a delimited list of the values of MyString for all of the objects inside myObjectList

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Select` instead of `ForEach`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a List<T> into a comma-separated list, using the class's Id property as the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588811/how-to-convert-a-listt-into-a-comma-separated-list-using-the-classs-id-prope)

Comment: Try : string MyListOfMyStrings = String.Join(",", myObjectList.Select(x => x.Mystring));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace where you are using ForEach with a linq statement like below:

```
string MyListOfMyStrings = String.Join(",", (from myObject in myObjectList select myObject.MyString).ToArray());
```

See the [MSDN guide for linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)